# Python 3 installation failed 'Keyset as registered is invalid'

Tags: python, installation, keyset

I have been trying to get Python 3 installed, but this error occurs:

[image]

I am running it on Windows 8 64-bit. I will keep trying. Thanks for the help. I didn't find any articles on the matter, so I came here.

Comment: IMHO This is not related to python, but to your windows. Try to download some registry repair tool it might help.

Comment: If not, can you link an article that has a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encounterd this problem for all applications, meaning that when I tried to install an application the same error will pop up "keyset as registered is invalid".

The solution for me was to delete the folder

```
S-1-5-21-3065067753-4167832549-3323262698-1001
```

found here:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA
```

Please make a copy of it before you try it