# VS 2015 RC Installation Failed On Windows 10 Technical Preview build 10074

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Microsoft Visual Studio Services Hub Fatal error during installation.
Log File [Here](http://expirebox.com/download/5069235890e7d79f99aeee9e6e051c3d.html)

Comment: Thanks Cristik for the information. Will take care here on. As of now my issue was resolved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My bad. Didn't read the log file well enough.
Solution was found from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589458/python-3-installation-failed-keyset-as-registered-is-invalid)

> The solution for me was to delete the folder
>
> S-1-5-21-3065067753-4167832549-3323262698-1001
>
> found here:
>
> %AppData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA