# Python Interpreter Installation

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to install python interpreter on windows 8 (64 bit).

I am trying to run the installer file but is shows the error:

```
"Keyset as registered is invalid"
```

Any idea what could be the problem & how could I fix it?

Comment: Have you looked into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589458/python-3-installation-failed-keyset-as-registered-is-invalid

Comment: Yes but it didn't help.

Comment: You should vet that you download a legit python package:  (e.g. https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/python-3.5.0rc1-amd64.exe )